# Haskell Basic IO

Tags: haskell

I want to create a Haskell IO function that uses a function to add an item of a data type to a list, then print a list of those datatypes.

```
DataType = Str Str Int []
```

It will always add the same item to the list.

I have this so far:

```
myFn = putStrLn( listAll ( addData "a" "b" 2000 [] testDatabase ) )
```

But I get the following errors:

> :20 Couldnt match type [Char] with Char, expected String, Actual [String]

Now this may be because listAll outputs a list of strings, and putStrLn can only handle one? But i'm not sure how i'd sort that out.

> :19 Function "a" is applied to 3 arguments

But "a" is not a function, it is part of the data type I want to be added (much confusion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the function `listAll` returns `[String]`, whereas `putStrLn` expects a `String`. You have essentially two options -

1. Convert the `[String]` to `String`, for example by using `concat` or `unlines`
2. Apply `putStrLn` to each element of the `[String]` in turn, by using something like `mapM_`

For option 1, you could write

```
main = putStrLn $ unlines $ listAll (addData "a" "b" 2000 [] testDatabase)
```

For option 2, you could write

```
main = mapM_ putStrLn $ listAll (addData "a" "b" 2000 [] testDatabase)
```

Comment: Ok now I have `fn = mapM_ putStrLn( listAll ( addData ("a" "b" 2000 []) testDatabase ) )`, the only error I get now is it saying "a" is applied to 3 arguements, when that whole section is meant to be the first argument of addData, with testDatabase being the second arguement.

Comment: What is the type of `addData`?

Comment: @Chillo, this: `("a" "b" 2000 [])` doesn't make sense. You're applying `"a"` as a function to three arguments. Haskell does not need parentheses to call functions, function application is simply juxtaposition.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `forM_` from Control.Monad:

```
import Control.Monad

myFn :: IO ()
myFn = forM_ (listAll ( addData "a" "b" 2000 [] testDatabase )) putStrLn
```

Comment: That works, thanks, but I am now left with the second error, in addData, where it says "a" is applied to 3 arguements, when it is not a function itself. I have tried fixing it by adding brackets from "a" to [] but it doesnt seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Chillo - Could you add the definition of `addData` to the question? If you haven't specified the type explicitly it may have inferred one different to the one you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your second error is because `"a" "b" 2000 []` is parsed as a function application, with `"a"` as the function. You cannot create a value of a new datatype in Haskell just by listing its subfields like that... there needs to be a *data constructor* name first. Exactly what to write depends on exactly how you have defined your new data type, but say your type declaration is

```
data MyNewType = MyDataConstructorName String String Int [SomeTypeYouDidn'tMention]
```

Then the expression for making your value would be

```
addData (MyDataConstructorName "a" "b" 2000 []) testDatabase
```